# Force application to restart from first Activity (when a permission is denied)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, activity-manager

It is known that when we ***deny*** permissions at runtime in Android 6.0 and ***resume*** the app from the recent menu, the app process is killed and the app is ***forcibly restarted***. This is allegedly in order to prevent any security snafus:

[image]

It is remarkable that, when resumed, ***the app restarts from the last `Activity` we left it on.*** The OS apparently keeps track of the last `Activity` the user visited.

Unfortunately, this is a problem, as it breaks the flow of the business logic. The user cannot be allowed to access the app midway in this manner.

My question is, is there a way to force the app to restart from the first `Activity` of the application, instead of the one the user left it on?

Are there any callbacks associated with an application restart / process kill / permissions toggle?

Is this a wrong-headed approach? If so, how? And what would be the correct approach?

**This behaviour has of course been observed before:**

**1.** [**Android Preview M: activity recreates after permission grant**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31432534)

**2.** [**Application is getting killed after enable/disable permissions from settings on Android M nexus 6**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32307786)

**3.** [**Android Marshmallow: permissions change for running app**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33785074)

**4.** [**All the permissions of my app are revoked after pressing “Reset app preferences”**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33896601)

**5.** [**Android 6 permission - Crashes when toggling permission in Setting and go back to app**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34865719)

Comment: You shouldn't need to know whether your app has a given permission up until the point where you try to use some feature that require that permission. At that point you take the usual steps: check and (if necessary), request.

Comment: @Michael: I do understand that. What I am trying to do is prevent the app from restarting from the last `Activity` the user left it on. Instead it should restart from the first `Activity` (i.e. the one that has an `intent-filter` with `action` `MAIN` and `category` `LAUNCHER`). Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Well, I haven't tried this, but I suppose you could call `checkSelfPermission` from `onResume`, and if it fails, start your root activity with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` set.

Comment: "Are there any callbacks associated with toggling the permissions at runtime?" -- no. "is there a way to force the app to restart from the first Activity of the application, and not the one the user left it on?" -- nothing automatic. Michael's solution might work, though I would do something to educate the user (e.g., explanatory dialog) before dumping back in some earlier activity.

Comment: What's wrong with just finishing the current `Activity`.  This go back to the start idea is not really how the Activity stack is supposed to work on Android.

Comment: @XaverKapeller: I would urge you to try this with a few apps. Chances are that this kind of behavior can potentially be a major source of bugs, and/or compromise the business logic of the app. This is why I'm asking for the app to be restarted from the first `Activity`.

Comment: No it does not, I would argue the exact opposite. Your job as a developer is to work together with the Android framework - not to look for ways to make it work like you want it to. If you are looking for an optimal solution that just works than don't try to kill the `Activity` stack. Instead change your implementation to and adapt to the way Android wants you to do this.

Comment: For example you talk about how you want to prevent the app from restarting from its last `Activity` when in fact nothing like that happens. That `Activity` never stopped being in the foreground and if you want to change that you either need to start a new `Activity` and go somewhere else or call `finish()` to return to the `Activity` before that - the reset and return to start that you want is not an option here. That's not how you are supposed to use that.

Comment: i would suggest, do not let the user get to that activity. What i mean is, if you want that the user cannot navigate ahead or back from a particular activity, then basically you can ask for that permission on the 1st activity itself. This would be bad practice of course, but depending on your question, i would say that you can use this.

Comment: for eg, if you have 7 activities, activity 4 is where you want the permission, if denied you want to load your app from activity 1. Then y not request permission on activity 1 itself? since you do not want the user to either come to activity 4 or activities 3 or 2.

Comment: @XaverKapeller: `when in fact nothing like that happens` I would urge you to read the posts I linked to if you don't believe me - others have observed this happening. And you can observe it it yourself - debug any app, and when you follow the steps I have mentioned, the app is restarted and the debug session is terminated. See for yourself ...

Comment: @vibhor_shri: interesting idea, but the problem occurs when the user minimizes the app, turns a permission off (in the app settings) and then resumes the app. Your solution will not prevent this problem from occurring ...

Comment: I am aware of that. That's not what this is about. Everything here works exactly as it is supposed to. Apps can be killed and restarted at any time without rime or reason - that's just what mobile operating systems do - Android gives you the tools to deal with that more than adequately. You just have to use them. What happens in that case is that the instance state is restored. If you implement your stuff correctly you shouldn't even notice that anything at all happens.

Comment: @XaverKapeller: `Apps can be killed and restarted at any time without rime or reason` - except that in this case, the app is restarted not randomly, but ***deterministically***, every time we turn off a permission. There is causality here, not randomness. And I'm trying to deal with that causality because it breaks the flow of my business logic.

Comment: It doesn't matter what causes this. What changes if you know that it happens deterministically? I would argue it gets easier because you absolutely know at what point you have to be sure that you can safely save and restore the state because as you say - it happens everytime.

Comment: @Y.S. did you figure out elegant solution for this?

Comment: @Niko: I do not even have an "inelegant" solution for this as of now. Do you??

Comment: @Y.S. Only ugly and fast solution I can figure out is System.exit(0). This is not a very common scenario that user will go to app settings and revoke permission.

Comment: @Niko: yes, but how do you know that the user has revoked a permission? As far as I know, there is no broadcast or callback for this. When and how do you call `System.exit(0)` ??

Comment: @Y.S. I check this out with 2 flags. First is that Activity onCreate parameter Bundle savedInstanceState != null, second variable is my internal business logic related. If you don't have such second variable, you could store permissions to shared preferences and on launch check if they have changed and then store static flag that something is gonna go wrong if I let my activity stack to "restart" in wrong order.

Comment: @Niko: I understand ... Though I should point out (and you probably know this) that `savedInstanceState` may be non-null for other reasons, or may be null even after a permission reset ... Without a callback or a broadcast, it is impossible to know for sure, I think.

Comment: @Y.S. Yes I do know it. Therefore I have a second variable in the check as well. Gotta refactor this thing later when got time, but this solution works for me now.

Comment: Wish I had that problem. My activity onDestroy gets called and I WANT the activity to restart on granted permission! Doesn't happen and I am trying to get it to happen.

Comment: @BrianReinhold: It normally should. You may have enabled 'Don't keep Activities' in Developer Settings. If so, please disable it.

Comment: @Y.S. did u solve this problem ??

Comment: @Jeeva: I'm afraid not ... :\

Comment: @Y.S. Have you find any solution for this issue because right now I facing the same issue but I haven't found any proper solution.

Comment: @DarshanMistry: If there were a system action broadcast when the user toggles a permission (something like **`ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED`** or **`ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED`**), then we might have a way to respond. Unfortunately there is no such [**documented**] action broadcast .... :\

Comment: @Y.S. No there is no broadcast fire when the user toggles a permission.

Comment: I faced the same issue. Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Did u mean this?

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView txt;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);

    txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityB.class);
            intent.putExtra("from","MainActivity");
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
}
```

ActivityB :

```
    public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {

String intentTxt="";
final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_PHONE_CALL = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);
    intentTxt = getIntent().getStringExtra("from");
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(intentTxt.equals("MainActivity")) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ActivityB.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityB.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_PHONE_CALL);
        }
    }
        intentTxt = "";
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_PHONE_CALL: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "32434"));
                startActivity(intent);

            } else {

                Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityB.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
}
```

You can start the splashActivity/HomeActivity from onRequestPermissionsResult of ActivityB.Check for permission in onResume of ActivityB so that the permission dialog appears when the ActivityB is called for the first time and also when resumed.

Answer (score 1):

You should be handling `Activity` (re)creation using the `Bundle` provided by `onCreate`, saved by `onSaveInstanceState`, more information [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#save-simple-lightweight-ui-state-using-onsaveinstancestate).

Pass in the `Bundle` all you need in order to recover from a previous state and restore your UI seamlessly. Your `Activity` can be recreated by many reasons, cancellation of permissions is just one of them, screen rotation is another, so as long as you can survive one, you can survive all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone is still looking for an answer on this, but I'd solve by reversing the logic, instead of waiting for a flag indicating the restart/recreate due to the denial of permission, pass a flag indicating that the Activity was started by another Activity and not recreated by the system.  So if FLAG doesn't come in extras then the activities stack must be destroyed and first activity lauched.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps for that.

1. Create a **Base Activity** that extends **AppcompatActivity** for maintaining all permissions and check permissions **onResume()**.
2. Extend **Base Activity** from all activities.
3. If any permission is denied, you can do whatever you want from **Base Activity**.

Happy Coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should put code to check the permission status in your `onResume` callback. If the user is switching to the System settings permission activity, your Activity will get paused. If the user enables a permission and then returns to your Activity, then `onResume` will be called, and you will have an opportunity to check for the new permission at that point. Then, you can do whatever you need to restart your activity, such as calling `startActivity` with an Intent that has `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` and launches your Activity again.

```
override fun onResume() {
  super.onResume()

  // check for permission
  checkPermissionsAndRestartIfNecessary()
}

private fun checkPermissionsAndRestartIfNecessary() {
  if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(...) {
    ...
  }
}
```