# Application is reboot when revoking application permissions

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-permissions, application-lifecycle

When I open settings from within the app and then cancel permission, the app reboots. How can I detect when the app is rebooted?

Comment: Changing permissions for an app will kill/restart it. Why do you want to detect when this happens?

Comment: i have a few config in Splash screen but when Application restart It doesn't run into splash screen, it runs into activity, it opens settings. I want to know that event to reopen the Splash screen.

Comment: I see. Does this answer your question? [Force application to restart from first Activity (when a permission is denied)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39204052/force-application-to-restart-from-first-activity-when-a-permission-is-denied)